# Using PHP mail() to send mail in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, email

I am doing a very simple subscription form, user fills in name and email then press subscribe button.

I don't understand why this is not working.. is there anything am missing here?

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" name='subscriptionForm' action='/' method='post'>
      <h4 class="form-signin-heading">Get new articles via email</h4>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
      <br/>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown" type="submit">Subscribe Me!</button>
      <br/><br/>
      <?php
        if (isset($_REQUEST['name']) && isset($_REQUEST['email']) ) 
          //if email is filled out, send email
          {
          $to = "myemail@gmail.com";
          $subject = "Thngs Of That Nature | Article Subscription";
          $name = $_POST['name'] ;
          $message = 'Hello there, I would like to subscribe to Thngs Of That Nature!' ;
          $from = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
          $headers = $name .'( '. $from .' )';
          mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
          echo "<div class='fb'>Awe! <b>"  .$name ." Stay sharP!";
        } else {
          echo "NOPE!";
        };

      ?>
    </form>
```

Comment: You missed your question

Comment: Except for the fact that your application could be hacked to send thousands of spam emails by injecting headers?

Comment: WHAT. IS. THE. PROBLEM?

Comment: @relentless its not sending the email

Comment: @D'loDeProjuicer Why isn't it sending email?  Do you get an error?  Or does the app look like email was sent, but then it is not received?  Are you sure this code executes?  How is it called?  Is there a greater context of this code we should be aware of?  Since you tagged this with AngularJS; how does AngularJS relate to the code you provided?

Comment: @Reboog711 there is no error, it is JUST not working, which is what has me puzzled. I have a site where the exact same code works. But here I am using it in angular, and that is why I have angular tag

Comment: @D'loDeProjuicer Does it create the HTTP call? Does your page even refresh? What does `mail()` return? Does it even enter the condition? What does `print_r($_REQUEST)` output? Do you get a blank page? Do your logs say anything? Do you get `NOPE` or `Awe`?

Comment: i find your lack of willingness to do any basic debugging disturbing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 problems.

**1)** `data-toggle="dropdown"` intercepts the HTTP call so `<?php .... ?>` doesn't get executed. I had to removing attribute.

**2)** Mixing `$_REQUEST[]` with `$_POST[]` seemed to cause its set of problems, I can only use one, and I had to use `$_POST[]`.